# Get all resources created by a helm release using k8s rest API

Tags: rest, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Is there a way I can get a list of all helm releases, and then all resources that have been created by this release, using the Kubernetes REST API?

I mean something similar to helm and kubectl commands

`helm list`

`kubectl get all --all-namespaces -l=release-name`

but using REST - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.23/

Comment: Hi Daria Domagała welcome to SO. Have you already considered just running `helm --debug` during `install` which will log all the manifests that it is deploying? I would guess that will be much easier than trying to walk every possible object in a cluster, including CRDs, that _could_ have been created. Good luck!

Comment: Another approach would be to use the kubernetes audit log to watch for creation events

Answer (score 2):

Helm is built on top of the Kubernetes API layer, in that it creates objects like Deployments and Services and stores its state in Secrets; but a Helm release is not itself a Kubernetes object and you can't directly use the Kubernetes API to access it.

If your application is in Go, then Helm 3 includes a [Go SDK](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#go-sdk), which essentially exposes most of the `helm` binary as Go-native library calls.  This isn't a network-visible API, though, and if your application is in any other language you won't be able to integrate with it.

If instead it's more important to be able to manipulate your application using Kubernetes's REST API than to be using Helm proper, one alternative is to write a program (a Kubernetes [controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/)) that interacts with the Kubernetes API, and have it be driven by a [custom resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/), a Kubernetes object that would include your application-specific configuration.  This pair is commonly called an [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/).  Much more so than a Helm chart, though, this involves actually writing code and not just dropping in bits of Kubernetes YAML.  (And, much more so than a Helm chart, you can unit-test more complex logic using your host language's native test tools.)

But in short, no, unless you can use the Helm Go SDK then there's not a good way to programmatically interact with a Helm chart beyond shelling out to the `helm` command.